# XNA Drawing Terrain in the wrong places

Tags: c#, xna, terrain

[image]

I need to draw a terrain and have a camera with surfacefollow in XNA, but in some places it doesnt draw what is suposed to draw and draws the terrain behind it. Any suggestions of what it may be?

```
 public void Draw()
            {
                camera.Effect.TextureEnabled = true;
                camera.Effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
                camera.Effect.World = worldMatrix;
                camera.Effect.Texture = texture;
                camera.Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

                device.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
                device.Indices = indexBuffer;

                for (int i = 1; i < (alturas.Height - 1); i++)
                {
                    device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 0, heights.Width * 2, (heights.Width * 2) * i, (heights.Width * 2) - 2);
                }

            }
```

heights is the texture of the height map. The construction of the vertices is working fine.

Comment: Would be better if we see your work as well..

Comment: It would be good see a screenshot, but I suppose you have a [similar problem][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003937/whats-wrong-with-my-xna-cube/22020417#22020417

Comment: You need to enable the dept buffer.  More info here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130016/xna-textured-primitives-are-see-through/26130467#26130467

Comment: I tried that in everyplace that calls the Device and nothing changed.